# !process 0 0 - NT symbols are incorrect, please fix symbols

Tags: windows-10, windbg

I get the same error when using `!process 0 0` every time - being in kernel debug mode or not doesn't seem to change anything.

Here's a command chain while opening `notepad.exe`

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00007ff6`27eb0000 00007ff6`27ee8000   notepad.exe
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fb890000 00007ffe`fba86000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f9990000 00007ffe`f9a4d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f90b0000 00007ffe`f9379000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fb820000 00007ffe`fb84a000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f8fd0000 00007ffe`f8ff2000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f9580000 00007ffe`f968b000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f9380000 00007ffe`f941d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`f9420000 00007ffe`f9520000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`faff0000 00007ffe`fb190000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fa110000 00007ffe`fa466000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fb440000 00007ffe`fb56b000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fadc0000 00007ffe`fae6e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`fa4d0000 00007ffe`fa56e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ffe`e2d70000 00007ffe`e300b000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.746_none_ca02b4b61b8320a4\COMCTL32.dll
(1208.ff0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1
         C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym
         ntdll.pdb
         432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491\ntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491\ntdll.pdb
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffe`fb960670 cc              int     3
```

The `.sympath` command :

```
0:000> .sympath 
Symbol search path is: srv*
Expanded Symbol search path is: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred
```

The `.reload` command :

```
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules
...............SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x3
         C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym
         ntdll.pdb
         432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491\ntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\432F2B8588C52E47219EE25E35F653491\ntdll.pdb
```

Finally the `!process 0 0` command :

```
0:000> !process 0 0
**** NT ACTIVE PROCESS DUMP ****
Could not get address of nt!KdVersionBlock.
unable to get nt!MmUserProbeAddress
NT symbols are incorrect, please fix symbols
```

I don't know what is going on. I tried deleting the `sym\ntdll.pdb` folder and re-downloading it but to no avail.

---

Edit - more info on request :

```
0:000> !lmi nt
Loaded Module Info: [nt] 
DBGHELP: SharedUserData - virtual symbol module
nt not found
0:000> vertarget
Windows 10 Version 19042 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Build layer:            -> 
Build layer:            -> 
Build layer:            -> 
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Mar 10 18:26:22.757 2021 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 14:38:24.474
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:51.162
  Kernel time: 0 days 0:00:00.015
  User time: 0 days 0:00:00.000


0:000> lm
start             end                 module name
00007ff6`54910000 00007ff6`54948000   notepad    (deferred)             
00007ffe`f9c40000 00007ffe`f9eda000   COMCTL32   (deferred)             
00007fff`09350000 00007fff`09372000   win32u     (deferred)             
00007fff`09540000 00007fff`095dd000   msvcp_win   (deferred)             
00007fff`09690000 00007fff`09959000   KERNELBASE   (deferred)             
00007fff`099e0000 00007fff`09ae0000   ucrtbase   (deferred)             
00007fff`09b30000 00007fff`09c3b000   gdi32full   (deferred)             
00007fff`09c70000 00007fff`09d0e000   msvcrt     (deferred)             
00007fff`09e20000 00007fff`09ece000   shcore     (deferred)             
00007fff`0a8d0000 00007fff`0a98d000   KERNEL32   (deferred)             
00007fff`0aa60000 00007fff`0aa8a000   GDI32      (deferred)             
00007fff`0aad0000 00007fff`0ac70000   USER32     (deferred)             
00007fff`0ad00000 00007fff`0ae2b000   RPCRT4     (deferred)             
00007fff`0b810000 00007fff`0bb65000   combase    (deferred)             
00007fff`0bc10000 00007fff`0be05000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\53F12BFE149A2F50205C8D5D66290B481\ntdll.pdb
0:000> .reload /f nt

"nt" was not found in the image list.
Debugger will attempt to load "nt" at given base 00000000`00000000.

Please provide the full image name, including the extension (i.e. kernel32.dll)
for more reliable results.Base address and size overrides can be given as
.reload <image.ext>=<base>,<size>.
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xD
         C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym
         nt
         FFFFFFFE
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\nt - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\n_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80070003
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xE
         C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         nt
         FFFFFFFE
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\nt - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\n_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/nt
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/n_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\system32\nt - file not found
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xF
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         nt
         FFFFFFFE
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\nt - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\n_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\nt\FFFFFFFE\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/nt
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/n_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/nt/FFFFFFFE/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo(HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH): 800C2F76 - ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGENG:  nt - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
DBGHELP: No header for nt.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: .\nt.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: nt missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for nt.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: nt.pdb - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nt
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nt
DBGHELP: nt_0 - no symbols loaded
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
```

Comment: the kernel symbolic name is `nt`; could you paste the output of the `!lmi nt` and `vertarget` commands? sometimes the symbols servers don't have the symbols for some versions of Windows (specially if you're in the insider program, it happens also for the stable releases from time to time).

Comment: @Neitsa I made an update - nt is not found. If it can help, I recently made all possible Windows updates - specifically version 20H2. I'm not in the insider program.

Comment: Ok strange, I have the exact same version, but we might have different kernels. in the debuger you can try to issue `!sym noisy` and then `.reload /f nt`; this should give you a bit of information on what going on with the symbols. If you want even more info, try `symchk.exe` (same folder as windbg (**not** preview)): `symchk.exe /v c:\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe`. This will give you a lot of information about the symbolic information for your kernel (and whether it can download the symbols or not from the symbol server). you might want to update your post with these info.

Comment: I am using WinDbg Preview is that the issue ? I made an edit with `lm` and `.reload /f nt`. I can't find symchk.exe on my system.

Comment: oh ok, I thought you were doing a kernel session debugging... [`!process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-process) is **only** for kernel debugging and it can't work in user-mode because in that case the debugger needs to read information  from the kernel space itself. Try `.hh !process` and look at the help file. Each commands comes with a "context" which tells you in which mode (kernel vs user) you can run a command.

Comment: I'm not in kernel debug on right now but I was when I made the post - I had the same error. I will reboot and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to WinDbg sorry. How do I open notepad.exe in debug mode [I have kernel debugging on now] ? I can use `process 0 0` now if I attach to the kernel and it will list all the running processes correctly.

Comment: I make no sense I mis-read the examples on MSDN but I get it now. I must use `!process 0 0` in kernel debugging and then select the process I'm interested in from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!process 0 0` will only work in *Attach to kernel* mode with Windows kernel debugging turned on.

To use `!pte` with a process, one has to set the process context with `.process /p pid` - the pid is a process id listed with `!process 0 0`.

To use `!vtop`, one has to specify the process `directoryBase` [along with a virtual address] which is also listed with `!process 0 0`.